# How to use Python 2.7.10 in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've installed and setup virtualenv in my project folder and I want to use 2.7.10 rather than the default 2.7.9

How do I do that in virtualenv?

Comment: Too few details about your environment.

Comment: Also make it clear if you're using `venv` or `virtualenv`.

Comment: Have you installed python 2.7.10?

Comment: Upgrade Python2.7 to 2.7.10 in your system and it would use the latest version by default.

Comment: @TonyRoczz no, I'm using the default python installed in my local system (Ubuntu 15.04) which is `2.7.9`

Comment: As suggested by @SudipKafle try to upgrade `python 2.7` to `python 2.7.10`

Answer (score 1):

Generally we can define the python path for virtual environment using `-p` option

For windows:
`virtualenv -p c:\python2.x <virtual env path>`

For Ubuntu:
`virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.x <virtual env path>`

Comment: I'm having trouble installing `2.7.10`. I downloaded this https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710/ and followed the instructions on the README but after `make install`, I'm getting `Makefile:1003: recipe for target 'libinstall' failed
make: *** [libinstall] Error 1`

Comment: try using `sudo apt-get install python 2.7.10` or try using `sudo make install`

Comment: I've run the `sudo apt-get install python 2.7.10` with no errors but `python --version` is still showing 2.7.10

Comment: @johnjullies I believe you wanted to run `virtualenv` with `python 2.7.10` and now you got it.

Comment: sorry it's a typo. I meant `2.7.9`

Comment: check your `/usr/bin` folder there will two folders `python 2.7.9` and `python2.7.10`. If not then there might have been a problem when installing `python 2.7.10`.